# How to access a TextView / an ImageView in a ListView-child element at X position..?

Tags: android, listview, textview

I want to access the child of a **ListView** at position x. The ListView has the following xml layout code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         android:orientation="horizontal"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="40dp"
         android:background="@drawable/bg_grad_iled">
    <ImageView 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:id="@+id/iv_icon" />
    <TextView android:id="@+id/tv_name"
        android:textColor="@color/kategorieTextColor"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:layout_weight=".50"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:padding="3px" 
        android:layout_marginLeft="8px"/>
    <TextView android:id="@+id/tv_comment"
        android:textColor="@color/kategorieTextColor"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:layout_weight=".20"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:padding="3px"/>
    <TextView android:id="@+id/tv_distance"
        android:textColor="@color/kategorieTextColor"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:layout_weight=".30"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:padding="3px"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

**How can I access, (e.g.) the textview 'tv_name' in the 5th child of the ListView?**
Thats my current listener:

```
lv1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Clicked", 1000).show();
                }
              });
```

Perhaps the adapter I use may be important? [Refer this](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/List14.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

when you click on the list item OnItemClickListener will return the view, so that you can get access through that view ..

Eg:

```
if you want to get text of tv_name at position 5 simply:



 public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, final int position,long arg3) 
                {
                 TextView text=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.tv_name);
                 Toast.makeText(this, text.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                             }
                  });
```

try it and get me the feedback

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Eclipse says "tv_name cannot be resolved or is not a field" :/. So whyever R.id.tv_name does not exist in this context..
Thats the code i am using right now:

`lv1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
           public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, final int position,long arg3) {
           TextView text=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.tv_name);
                    Toast.makeText(context, text.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
             }
           });`

Comment: just clean your project once and run it,come fast time to go now for me

Comment: the text view object? in the onclick event

Comment: you used adapter, so i think in holder you created that one like this:   holder.text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_name);

Comment: yes you are right..
the holder.name = (TextView)convert........(R.id.tv_name);
is in the private static class EfficientAdapter extends BaseAdapter { ... }